# MySQL pivot row run in sql fiddle but not work in syntax model codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i use code to use MySQL pipot row at this link [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)
it's work on query editor and SQL fidle. but it's not work when i use query to model of codeIgniter

in Model PHP on Code Igniter i use code like this:

```
$query=$this->db->query("
   SET @sql = NULL;
   SELECT
   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
   CONCAT(
     'count(case when tahun = ''',
     tahun,
     ''' then 1 end) AS tahun_',
     replace(tahun, ' ', '')
   )
   ) INTO @sql
   from tb_tahun;

   SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.jenis_perjal, ', @sql, ' from tb_jenis_perjal pt
   left join tb_kebutuhan_perjal s
     on pt.id_jenis_perjal = s.id_jenis_perjal
   left join tb_tahun pd
     on s.id_tahun = pd.id_tahun
   group by pt.jenis_perjal');

   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
");
```

result of query :

```
Err Number : 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'count(case when' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the text in a variable and pass that variable as parameter to run method

```
    $var = "SET @sql = NULL;
       SELECT
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
       CONCAT(
         'count(case when tahun = ''',
         tahun,
         ''' then 1 end) AS tahun_',
         replace(tahun, ' ', '')
       )
       ) INTO @sql
       from tb_tahun;

       SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.jenis_perjal, ', @sql, ' from tb_jenis_perjal pt
       left join tb_kebutuhan_perjal s
         on pt.id_jenis_perjal = s.id_jenis_perjal
       left join tb_tahun pd
         on s.id_tahun = pd.id_tahun
       group by pt.jenis_perjal');

       PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
       EXECUTE stmt;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";

     $query=$this->db->query($var);
```